# Android Socket to Python Server - Timeout

Tags: android, python, sockets

I am trying to write an app that sends a string to a specified IP address and Port number. The destination already has a server that accepts strings, but for some reason, the app cannot establish a socket with the server, it keeps timing out. I have only written code, so if I have to do something else like port forward on either the client or server end, please let me know.

The goal of this app is to take in a string for an IP address, a string for the Port number, and a String for the message to send to the destination. After pressing the Send button, the app will send the message to the IP and Port number defined, and display a response from the server.

This also will be used in two applications: once between the Android App and a Python server, and other between the Android App and custom hardware. Hopefully there is a solution to fit both cases.

Client Code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView recieve;
        EditText addressText, portText, messageText;
        Button send;

        Socket socket = null;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_customize_gateway, container, false);

            recieve = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            addressText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            portText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            messageText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

            send = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.send);
            send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AsyncSend aSend= new AsyncSend(addressText.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(portText.getText().toString()), messageText.getText().toString());
                    aSend.execute();
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }

        public class AsyncSend extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            String address;
            int port;
            String message;
            String response;
            AsyncSend(String addr, int p, String mes) {
                address = addr;
                port = p;
                message = mes;
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                Socket socket = null;
                try {
                    System.out.println("Test");
                    socket = new Socket(address, port);
                    System.out.println("Test");
                    DataOutputStream writeOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    writeOut.writeUTF(message);
                    writeOut.flush();


                    ByteArrayOutputStream writeBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    int bytesRead;
                    InputStream writeIn = socket.getInputStream();

                    while((bytesRead = writeIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        writeBuffer.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                        response += writeBuffer.toString("UTF-8");
                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    response = "Unknown HostException: " + e.toString();
                    System.out.println(response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
                    System.out.println(response);
                } finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        recieve.setText(response);
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                recieve.setText(response);
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Server Code:

```
import http.server
import socket
import threading
import socketserver

import pymongo

import smtplib

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        #Connect to database
        try:
            from pymongo import MongoClient
            dbclient = MongoClient()
            db = dbclient.WDI_database
            print("Database Connected")
        except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure as e:
            print("Database Failed: {}".format(e))

        col = db.users

        data2 = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        print("Server: {}".format(data2));
        data = data2.split("||")
        username, password, camunits, homunits = data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]
        post = {"user": username,
                "pass": password,
                "cam": camunits,
                "disp": homunits}
        col.insert(post)
        print(col.count())

        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
        response = bytes("{} Received data for: {}".format(cur_thread, username), 'ascii')
        self.request.sendall(response)

class ThreadedUDPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        print("Recieved: " + data.decode("utf-8"))
        socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "", 5000

    tcpserver = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT-1), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=tcpserver.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    print("TCP serving at port", PORT-1)

    while True:
        pass
    tcpserver.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably because I didn't port forward, so my connection got blocked by my router. I opened the port on both the router and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Socket` class is too low-level for your purposes and fraught with potential gotcha's. I suggest using `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` instead.

Comment: Can I keep the server the same, or do I have to recode the server too?

Comment: No, nothing needs to be changed on the server. As long as you're using HTTP protocol, HttpClient is for you!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will keep this in mind. There is another part of this project that I didn't mention: this client/server dynamic will also have to be mirrored but the server is a custom made piece of hardware that may not be able to handle HTTP connections, so I would like to have that connection as low or simple as possible.